# R cut function - dividing into wrong groups

Tags: r, cut

I have a very big data set of sale prices. 
A short version of it looks like this:

```
prices_t

# A tibble: 3,000 x 1
   sale_price
        <dbl>
 1    6625000
 2    3936272
 3    8000000
 4    3192840
 5   16232000
 6   10350000
 7     499000
 8     529500
 9     423000
10     501000
# ... with 2,990 more rows
```

I am trying to divide the data into equal range categories using the cut function:

```
prices_t$sale_price_category <- 
  cut(prices_t$sale_price, breaks = 10, dig.lab = 50)
```

However, the output is has not divided the ovbservations to the correct groups, and has created false categories (the data has no negative values)

```
prices_t
# A tibble: 3,000 x 2
   sale_price sale_price_category   
        <dbl> <fct>                 
 1    6625000 (-1039499.5,104000450]
 2    3936272 (-1039499.5,104000450]
 3    8000000 (-1039499.5,104000450]
 4    3192840 (-1039499.5,104000450]
 5   16232000 (-1039499.5,104000450]
 6   10350000 (-1039499.5,104000450]
 7     499000 (-1039499.5,104000450]
 8     529500 (-1039499.5,104000450]
 9     423000 (-1039499.5,104000450]
10     501000 (-1039499.5,104000450]
# ... with 2,990 more rows
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, can anyone explain?

Comment: I think you probably have one extremely high value. Can you check `max(prices_t$sale_price)`? You can reproduce this by doing `cut(c(1:100 * 10000, 543212345678907), 10, dig.lab = 10)`

Comment: I do have one extreme value,  is there a way to divide the extreme values into groups separately?

Comment: Amidavid you can set the breaks to whatever you want using `breaks = c(0, 100000, 200000, ...` inside `cut`. If you want a final "any number above 50,000,000" category, just set your final value in `breaks` to `Inf`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want r to automatically set the boundaries, except for the "extremes" group

Comment: @Amidavid, then you decide on the threshold above which you want R to ignore the values, then set `breaks = c(seq(min(prices_t$sale_price), threshold, 10), Inf)`. This will allow R to choose 10 equally spaced cuts based on the data, plus an extra category for numbers above your threshold.